# Rails model complex inheritance associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, polymorphic-associations

I have two classes `Ad`s and `Zone`s which both inherit from a class called `Tracked` which in turn contains several `Event`s. The idea is that `Ad`s as well as `Zone`s can be associated with various events (i.e. 'View', 'Click', 'Conversion'). Those events must be tracked.

***How would I go about and model that using `ActiveRecord`s? What would the migration code look like?***

This is what I got so far:

***Event:***

```
class Event < ActiveRecord :: Base

  attribute :event_date
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
[...]
end
```

***Tracked:***

```
class Tracked < ActiveRecord :: Base

  self.abstract_class = true
  has_many :views, class_name: "Event"
  has_many :clicks, class_name: "Event"
  has_many :conversions, class_name: "Event"

  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
[...]
end
```

***Ad:***

```
class Ad < Tracked

  attribute :size, :content
  attr_accessor :width, :height
  belongs_to :advertisers
  has_and_belongs_to_many :campaigns
[...]
end
```

***Campaign:***

```
require 'date'

class Campaign < ActiveRecord :: Base

  attribute :name, :target_url,
            :expiration_date,:categories,
            :billing_type, :budget, :budget_type,
            :cp_click, :cp_view, :cp_conversion

  belongs_to :advertiser
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ads
  has_many :zones
[...]
end
```

At first I thought that I may want to use the `through` association but since it is paramount for me to distinguish between those three events (View, Click, Conversion) I think that I can' apply that pattern. Therefore I think I got to use `Polymorphic Associations`.

Please note that the code I pasted contains all the necessary information to create the model i.e. there are no attributes or associations that I left out. Also I know how to write migration code for all the attributes/associations that don't belong to the problem described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Polymorphic Association**

To implement a polymorphic associations here, Ads and Zones should both use:

```
has_one :tracked, as: :trackable
```

You wouldn't need this line in Events: `belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true` since you already have it in Tracked.

You then need to run some migrations to set up Tracked to handle the `trackable` association ([this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) explains that better than I could).

I think you would need to also remove `self.abstract_class = true` in Tracked since it will now be represented in the db.

**There is perhaps a better way to approach this:**

Perhaps you would be better off creating the 'views', 'clicks' and 'conversion' associations directly on Ads and Zones and then including any shared logic with a module.

You could take the logic of Tracked, move it into a 'trackable' module and including that module in Ads and Zones (if you're using Rails 4 you can [wrap this up in a 'trackable' concern](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns)).

You would also move the following associations into Ads and Zones:

```
  has_many :views, class_name: "Event"
  has_many :clicks, class_name: "Event"
  has_many :conversions, class_name: "Event"
```

You then wouldn't need the Tracked class any more.

This approach would mean you could call `Ad.first.views` as opposed to `Ad.first.tracked.views` which would be the case if you used a polymorphic association.

Comment: Great idea! I really forgot that I could seperate the data model and the logic of trackables.